# Error when converting Flash to C#

Tags: c#, flash, actionscript, base64

I have the following method in Flash which writes two `ByteArrays` and then base64 encodes them

```
private function generateSignature(data:String, secretKey:String):String {             
    var secretKeyByteArray:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
    secretKeyByteArray.writeUTFBytes(secretKey);
    secretKeyByteArray.position = 0;

    var dataByteArray:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
    dataByteArray.writeUTFBytes(data);
    dataByteArray.position = 0;

    var hmac:HMAC = new HMAC(new SHA1());            
    var signatureByteArray:ByteArray = hmac.compute(secretKeyByteArray, dataByteArray);
    return Base64.encodeByteArray(signatureByteArray);
}
```

In my C#, I have:

```
string GenerateSignature(string secretKey, string base64Policy)
{
    byte[] secretBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(secretKey);
    byte[] dataBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(base64Policy);
    HMACSHA1 hmac = new HMACSHA1(secretBytes);
    byte[] signature = hmac.ComputeHash(dataBytes);
    return ByteToString(signature);
}
```

But, I get a different result set from the Flash version compared to the C# version.  Can anyone spot anything that is obviously wrong?

EDIT

Here is the `ByteToString` method:

```
static string ByteToString(byte[] buffer)
{
   string binary = string.Empty;
   for (int i = 0; i < buffer.Length; i++)
   {
      binary += buffer[i].ToString("X2"); // Hex Format
   }
   return binary;
}
```

Comment: When you say you get a different result give us an example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks pretty much the same;  that said, I would suggest using `Convert.ToBase64String` instead of your `ByteToString` method, the string concatenation in there is generally considered very bad practice.

I am also not 100% sure if Base 64 encoding is logically the same as appending `byte.ToString("X2")` for each byte to a string (although it could well be).

Other than that, it shouldn't be too difficult to debug and figure out where the two start to deviate...

Comment: Thanks.  It has been bugging me for a while.  I thought I was double encoding somewhere along the lines.

Answer (score 2):

Your ByteToString function merely returns a hexadecimal version of the signature.  Your flash version base 64 encodes it.  There's a big difference between converting something to a hexadecimal string, and base 64 encoding.

Use `Convert.ToBase64String` instead of ByteToString.

Answer (score 0):

Flash might not be emitting the BOM (Byte Order Mark), where C# (.Net) does.

```
public static readonly Encoding Utf8NoBom = new UTF8Encoding(false);
```

According to [the Flash Documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/ByteArray.html) you are using the correct encoding on the C# end; so this is the only possible alternative (it didn't have anything to say about the BOM).